# Is there an alternate proof or an exposition of: Exponential lower bound for $\Sigma\Pi\Sigma$ circuits [Grigoriev-Karpinski(1998)]?

Tags: circuit-complexity, arithmetic-circuits

Is there an alternate proof or an exposition of the result of Grigoriev and Karpinski (STOC 1998, doi:[10.1145/276698.276872](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/276698.276872)) on the [exponential lower bounds for Depth 3 arithmetic circuits](http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~grigorev/pub/determinant_stoc.ps) computing $\mathsf{DET}_{n\times n}$ over a fixed finite field?

I could not understand section 2 of the paper. What is the intuition behind considering the F-linear operator $T_g$?

Answer (score 7):

There was a subsequent extension by [Grigoriev and Razborov (PS)](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~razborov/depth3.ps) that has a shorter exposition of proof.